# Get the image position/location of an image in .xlsx file using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I can only get the image data through this method `.getAllPictures()`

```
List<XSSFPictureData> lst = (List)workbook.getAllPictures();
```

I get this whenever I use the `getShapes()`

```
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:149)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavacJavaCompiler.addJavacError(JavacJavaCompiler.java:92)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavacJavaCompiler.compile(JavacJavaCompiler.java:71)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavaAwareCompilationUnit.gotoPhase(JavaAwareCompilationUnit.java:97)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:529)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.compile(FileSystemCompiler.java:55)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.doCompilation(FileSystemCompiler.java:210)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.runCompiler(Groovyc.java:1078)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.compile(Groovyc.java:1129)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.execute(Groovyc.java:748)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
```

2015-04-21 09:54:36,457 ERROR StackTrace Full Stack Trace:
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

Is it possible or is there a way so I can get the image position/location in a .xlsx file?

Comment: Added POI tag so people who know about POI see this question

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the position via the XSSFPicture.getClientAnchor() method, the ClientAnchor has a row/column location and an pixel-offset which should allow to get the information you are looking for, e.g.:

```
XSSFDrawing dp = wb.getSheetAt(0).createDrawingPatriarch();
List<XSSFShape> pics = dp.getShapes();
XSSFPicture inpPic = (XSSFPicture)pics.get(0);

XSSFClientAnchor clientAnchor = inpPic.getClientAnchor();

System.out.println("col1: " + clientAnchor.getCol1() + ", col2: " + clientAnchor.getCol2() + ", row1: " + clientAnchor.getRow1() + ", row2: " + clientAnchor.getRow2());
System.out.println("x1: " + clientAnchor.getDx1() + ", x2: " + clientAnchor.getDx2() +  ", y1: " + clientAnchor.getDy1() +  ", y2: " + clientAnchor.getDy2());
```

will print out something like

```
col1: 0, col2: 2, row1: 1, row2: 7
x1: 252000, x2: 63720, y1: 60480, y2: 201600
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but I've already done that and its kinda weird coz of the method 'getShapes()'. Because it displays an error "cannot find symbol" in which it pertains to 'getShapes()'. Is there a way to get rid of this error? btw my java version is 1.7

Comment: see my edited post. Is that what you're looking for? im sorry if that's wrong coz im just a newbie. Please tell me if that's wrong so I can edit it. Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately this does not show anything about POI, it seems to be the output of Gradle/Ant, but the actual error output is missing...

Comment: can you suggest what to do? should I upgrade/update something?

Comment: There is way to less information about your actual problem to be able to suggest anything, only if you can provide more information we will be able to help... The current exception is from the build-tool, not from your application/test itself.

Comment: can i ask ,what build-tool you're using?